# How to execute sql query include where condition of time interval by python

Tags: python, sql-server

I want to perform SQL query by using pyodbc library via pycharm IDE. My data source is Microsoft SQL Server.

```
import pandas as pd SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query('select * from tblprofilewhimp_norm where MeterpointID = 111602 and Date_M > 2016-11-01 00:15:00', conn)
```

I get this error:

> pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from tblprofilewhimp_norm where MeterpointID = 111602 and Date_M > 2016-11-01 00:15:00': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '00'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

However, it didn't work because the formation of datetime in SQL Server may follow this '2016-11-01 00:15:00'. On the other hand, the SQL Server datetime format cannot satisfied python format.

Thus, how can I correct this problem?

Comment: String literals as dates **must be** enclosed in single quotes! Use `'2016-11-01 00:15:00'` instead of just `2016-11-01 00:15:00`

Comment: yes, sir but when we enclosed with single quotes like this SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query('select * from tblprofilewhimp_norm where MeterpointID = 111602 and Date_M > '2016-11-01 00:15:00', conn), the statement cannot run by pd.read_sql_query(), It alway show the error as 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: _SyntaxError: invalid syntax_ ... you're inside a '-string literal, so add `\'` escape sequences where marc_s suggested `'` characters?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Oh, thank you very much sir, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the f-string (f" ") fuctionality like this:

```
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(f"select * from tblprofilewhimp_norm where MeterpointID = 111602 and Date_M > '2016-11-01 00:15:00'", conn)
```